# Client side validation for PHP project good or bad? And how to improve the PHP project?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, client-side-validation

new to PHP. After around hours of learning&practising I have created a small PHP project with MySQL database for check/create/edit/delete employee's information.

So here are my questions to improve it(as a good and smart php project standard, doesn't have to be a enterprise levelled one):
Should I use more Javascript to do the client side validation , or use PHP functions to do the job mostly? (e.g. check if form data was entered with the correct format )

To modify the employee's information , what should I do to make sure the data was created/edited with the same standard inside database(e.g. first & second name should always starting with the one(and the only) upper case letter no matter what did user entered into the forms), javascript, php function or the sql queries? I think they could all make it working but which one is the best way and why?

This kind of code is driving me crazy

```
<input type="text" name="inputFname" class="field-divided" placeholder="First"value="<?php echo $emp['f_name'] ?>"/>
```

Any better way to make the php code separated with the html code?

Comment: While client-side js is good for immediate user response, never trust the request received by the server and always validate server side

Comment: always validate server side, optionally validate client side

Comment: You should do both. Client-side so you can prevent the form from being submitted if wrong and server-side because you should never trust the client side to be unaltered.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I am thinking about check server side mainly, and check client side for warning the user only.

Comment: client side validation will be for making him lazy and server side validation will be for all user and db safety So if client don't have to compromise with his comfort and safety  your validation is perfect :D

Comment: client-side validation is great for non-hacks. Most sites that have it can be bypassed. Those that don't comprehend that haven't hung out in Fiddler, once from the Microsoft guy, now from Telerik

Answer (score 1):

Any and all data coming from an untrustworthy source (the client, which can be manipulated by a hostile user) needs to be validated and sanitized within a controlled, secure environment (the server, which is locked away where end-users can't get at it) before being allowed contact with the database.

You can (and should) also perform "bozo-test" validation at the client to ensure completeness, correct formatting &c.; client-side validation allows you to inform the user of an error immediately without the overhead of a round-trip to the server. Keep in mind, though, that client-side validation **can not protect you from an actively hostile user.**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer with details, thank you :D Trying out the server side validation function at moment.